How can I fix issue with amazon-cognito cookies size being > 4k
I inherited a large nextjs react app that makes heavy use of amazon-cognito. Users are getting nginx 400 "Request Header or Cookie Too Large" error all the time now. It's not good!
Something is growing the size of the 3 amazon-cognito cookies:
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.access 1177 bytes
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.idToken 1396 bytes
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.refresh 1892 bytes
1177+1396+1892 = 4465!
What are the simple changes I can make to triage the problem without breaking login but getting these cookie sizes tamed?

Yes. You need to rebuild the auth portion of the front end to use custom apis.
You can create your own api to manage the auth request.
Then, pass back just the token to your front end website.
From there save the token into local storage manually.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/cognito-identity-provider/command/AdminInitiateAuthCommand/
